# Can I Trigger MySQL Event in every five second

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to run this sql command in every 5 sec in my MySQL server.
is it possible?

```
UPDATE comments SET Showed = '1' WHERE Showed = '0'
```

Comment: You can if you create an event (as in title) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html - though it might trip over itself if the update has a lot to do..

Comment: thanks, please tell me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother.  Use a view:

```
create table comments (
    . . . 
    showed_dt datetime
);

create view v_comments (
    select c.*,
           (showed_dt > now() - interval 5 second) as showed
    from comments c;
```

You don't want to incur the overhead of updating a bunch of rows every five seconds, particularly if there is a simple way to avoid doing that.